# firefox vaapi acceleration

Tags: firefox, 15.04, html5, vaapi

How can I enable **html5** hw acceleration in firefox 38 ? (running on ubuntu 15.04) with vaapi via gstreamer1.0-vaapi (installed). I have intel hd 4600.

Comment: [There's a bugreport](https://bugzil.la/563206) about it. They're planning to enable first GPU accelerated layers, accordingly to them without it there's little gains.